# Activating a profile by default

Tags: maven-2, maven

I'm using Maven 3.0.3.  I need to define a variable in my script ("env").  I have a `<profiles>` section in my pom in which I define the variable per `<profile>` element ...

```
<profile>
  <id>qa</id>
  <properties>
    <env>qa</env>
    ...
  </properties>
</profile>
```

In my pom.xml, how do I activate a profile only if none was specified via the "-P" command line option (and hence set the variable if it was not defined)?  I tried the below,

```
<profile>
  <id>dev</id>
  <activation>
    <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    <property>
      <name>env</name>
      <value>dev</value>
    </property>
  </activation>
  <properties>
    <url>http://localhost:8080/manager</url>
    <server>nnadbmon-dev-tomcat</server>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

but running the command "mvn compile" fails because the enforcer plugin I set up requires that I define an "env" variable.  Here's the code I run for my enforcer plugin ...

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>enforce-property</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>enforce</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <rules>
          <requireProperty>
            <property>env</property>
            <message>Environment missing.  This should be either dev, qa, or prod, specified as part of the profile (pass this as a parameter after -P).</message>
            <regex>^(dev|qa|production)$</regex>
            <regexMessage>Incorrect environment.  Expecting one of dev, qa, or prod.</regexMessage>
          </requireProperty>
        </rules>
        <fail>true</fail>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Do you want to just provide a default for the 'env' property?

Comment: Yes, I want to provide a default for the env property.

Comment: please post your enforcer config. You have not, in fact, defined an 'env' property. You'd just set a profile to run if such a property happens to exist and has a certain value. You could add a default env property to the properties element with some other value.

Comment: Hi, I added my enforcer config.  I don't understand the rest of your comment, though.  How can I activate a profile by default if the above is not the way to do it?

Comment: Why are you using the enforcer at all? Just set it 'activeByDefault' and take away the enforcer.

Answer (score 52):

I know it was a long time ago, but I had this problem just now, so... You should do that:

```
<profile>
    <id>dev</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <env>dev</env>
        <url>http://localhost:8080/manager</url>
        <server>nnadbmon-dev-tomcat</server>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

Comment: Also note: activeByDefault profiles are not selected if any other profiles are more actively selected through other activation rules or -P commandline.

Comment: @GregDomjan indeed, in my case I have added `<activation>
                <property>
                    <!-- Just pass -Dto-disable to disable the profile -->
                    <name>to-disable</name>
                    <value>!true</value>
                </property>
            </activation>`
then when I run `mvn help:active-profiles` I can see that the profile is activated by default even if I pass other profiles on the command line with the option `-Pmyprofile` etc.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for what I think you want is http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Activation

Comment: Hi, I edited my question to include what I tried (basically adding "<activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>"), but my build still fails if I leave off the "-P" directive (because the enforcer plugin isn't finding the "env" property).  If you can provide additional info and examples, it is appeciated, - Dave

Comment: @Dave You can type in a: mvn help:active-profiles to see which profiles are active by default.