# Vaadin + Spring Boot Production mode build with a runtime error: Failed to determine 'npm' tool

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, docker, vaadin-flow

**UPDATE ON THE SOLUTION**
This bug seems to have been the cause of the problem: https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/6657

While the fix is rolled out the marked answer can be used as a workaround

**Background**

I'm in the process of creating a dockerized, Spring Boot + Vaadin flow based [portal](https://github.com/tlvlp/iot-portal) for my [IoT project](https://github.com/tlvlp/iot-project-summary).

**Problem**

The portal works well running from my machine in Vaadin's development mode, with npm installed, but I can't seem to get the right setup for creating a lightweight deployment jar that already contains all the generated front end components.

When I'm running the service in a Docker container, I get the error that it cannot find npm but I assume that it shouldn't be needed for a production deployment

```
at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.DevModeInitializer.initDevModeHandler(DevModeInitializer.java:327)
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$DevModeServletContextListener.contextInitialized(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:323)
    ... 46 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.vaadin.flow.server.ExecutionFailedException: 

Failed to determine 'npm' tool.
Please install it either:
  - by following the https://nodejs.org/en/download/ guide to install it globally
  - or by running the frontend-maven-plugin goal to install it in this project:
  $ mvn com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.7.6:install-node-and-npm -DnodeVersion="v12.13.0"
```

**Docker file** without npm:

```
FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim

ARG PROJECT
ARG SERVICE_PORT
ARG JAR_FILE

EXPOSE ${SERVICE_PORT}

RUN mkdir /${PROJECT}
WORKDIR /${PROJECT}

ADD target/${JAR_FILE} ./app.jar

CMD ["java","-jar","app.jar"]
```

**pom.xml** (updated!)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.tlvlp</groupId>
    <artifactId>iot-portal</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.2</version>
    <name>iot-portal</name>
    <description>tlvlp IoT server portal</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <vaadin.version>14.0.12</vaadin.version>
        <dockerfile.maven.version>1.4.13</dockerfile.maven.version>
        <flow.server.prod.version>2.0.17</flow.server.prod.version>
        <!--    DOCKER IMAGE ARGS   -->
        <docker.project.repository>tlvlp/iot-portal</docker.project.repository>
        <service.port>8600</service.port>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <properties>
                <activatedProperties>prod</activatedProperties>
                <vaadin.productionMode>true</vaadin.productionMode>
            </properties>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flow-server-production-mode</artifactId>
                    <version>${flow.server.prod.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>

            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>flow-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${flow.server.prod.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build-frontend</goal>
                                    <goal>copy-production-files</goal>
                                    <goal>package-for-production</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                        <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${dockerfile.maven.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>prod</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build</goal>
                                    <goal>push</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <repository>${docker.project.repository}</repository>
                            <tag>${project.version}</tag>
                            <tag>latest</tag>
                            <buildArgs>
                                <PROJECT>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}</PROJECT>
                                <SERVICE_PORT>${service.port}</SERVICE_PORT>
                                <JAR_FILE>${project.build.finalName}.jar</JAR_FILE>
                            </buildArgs>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <properties>
                <activatedProperties>dev</activatedProperties>
                <vaadin.productionMode>false</vaadin.productionMode>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.profiles.active=@activatedProperties@
```

**application-prod.properties**

```
vaadin.compatibilityMode=false
vaadin.servlet.productionMode=true
```

I appreciate any guidance :)

All the code can be found on the master branch of the project's public repository: https://github.com/tlvlp/iot-portal

Comment: Are you running in production mode? You can enable profile by default as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849483/activating-a-profile-by-default

Comment: @anasmi thanks, I'm running the maven build with the prod profile and since my last update I have managed to make spring-boot use the prod profile at runtime, but Vaadin still seems to try to use the dev profile and looks for npm.  I have updated the pom.xml above and added the relevant parts of the properties files.

Comment: I did not see <packaging>jar</packaging> in your pom.xml, oy should ne there in thr beginning.

Comment: @TatuLund it is included in the spring-boot-starter-parent project referenced as the parent in my pom. I'm able to build the jar and by looking at the contents, it contains the pre-built frontend components (but I'm new to the front end world, so I might be mistaken) but for some reason I'm not able to make Vaadin to use them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally managed to figure out the solution to the problem.
It was a correct assumption that npm is not required to run the production application.
What wasn't clear [from even the official guide](https://vaadin.com/docs/flow/production/tutorial-production-mode-basic.html) that although adding the following property to the prod build profile does populate to the built jar file, but

**in itself does NOT trigger Vaadin to run in production mode (at least not together with SpringBoot):**

```
<vaadin.productionMode>true</vaadin.productionMode>
```

**Solution:**

What ended up solving the problem is to assign the value of the same parameter in the SpringBoot properties file as well.
Then it started to use the assets generated using npm in build time.

Here is the **application.properties** file (shared by both dev and prod properties files).

```
spring.profiles.active=@spring.activatedProperties@
vaadin.productionMode=@vaadin.productionMode@
vaadin.compatibilityMode=false
```

Here is the complete and updated and working pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.tlvlp</groupId>
    <artifactId>iot-portal</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.2</version>
    <name>iot-portal</name>
    <description>tlvlp IoT server portal</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <vaadin.version>14.0.12</vaadin.version>
        <dockerfile.maven.version>1.4.13</dockerfile.maven.version>
        <flow.server.prod.version>2.0.17</flow.server.prod.version>
        <!--    DOCKER IMAGE ARGS   -->
        <docker.project.repository>tlvlp/iot-portal</docker.project.repository>
        <service.port>8600</service.port>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <properties>
                <spring.activatedProperties>prod</spring.activatedProperties>
                <vaadin.productionMode>true</vaadin.productionMode>
            </properties>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flow-server-production-mode</artifactId>
                    <version>${flow.server.prod.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>

            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>flow-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${flow.server.prod.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
                                    <goal>build-frontend</goal>

                                </goals>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                        <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${dockerfile.maven.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>prod</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build</goal>
                                    <goal>push</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <repository>${docker.project.repository}</repository>
                            <tag>${project.version}</tag>
                            <tag>latest</tag>
                            <buildArgs>
                                <PROJECT>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}</PROJECT>
                                <SERVICE_PORT>${service.port}</SERVICE_PORT>
                                <JAR_FILE>${project.build.finalName}.jar</JAR_FILE>
                            </buildArgs>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <properties>
                <spring.activatedProperties>dev</spring.activatedProperties>
                <vaadin.productionMode>false</vaadin.productionMode>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I have recently had the same struggle I have the following solution. The easiest way I found to have Java and Nodejs/NPM was to install it to the java base image. This will not be a small docker image. `mvn clean package -Pproduction` the vaadin root directory. Then edit the Dockerfile to include the installation like so: https://gitlab.com/snippets/1913782

Then build and run the image. Build time and image size will increase a lot. I would love to see some suggestions or additional progress made on this process. Coming from Vaadin8 into 14 has created numerous headaches with having to learn why non-Java things are broken.

Comment: Thanks for the response, in the meantime I have figured out another solution, I just posted it below. I have to agree that it is a real headache and the documentation is not clear in many regards. Hope that it helps to simplify your workflow as well!

Comment: I also just found out that this bug was the source of the problem: https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/6657